# How to plot two columns of pandas dataframe as horizontal barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to compare between 2 columns in my dataframe, and want to plot them as a horizontal barplot using Seaborn. In the plot below is just one column plotted ('budget2019').

[image: actual plot with just one year 'budget2019' plotted]

1) How can I plot the second column ('budget2018') next to it, so that one can better see the evolution between both columns' values, and compare visually both bars, for each "ministry"?

2) How can I put the x-value at the end of each bar, so one can see (read) the x-value on each bar, and hasn't to go with the eyes down, and try to approximate the value? Because now on the actual plot one can't really read the x-value directly from a bar. (pretty difficult to get the exact value when looking at the plot)

3) After I get it to plot the 'budget2018' bars next to 'budget2019' bars, is there a way to also put the evolution in percent on the plot? So that it's visually better readable, how much evolution in % between both columns is?

Here is a look at my dataframe:

[image: a part of my small dataframe]

And here is the code I'm using to plot for now:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

#ax = sns.barplot(x="budget2018", y="ministere", data=budget, label="Total")
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="budget2019", y="ministere", data=budget, label="Budget 2019")

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

PS: If it is not doable with Seaborn, a solution with Matplotlib alone would be also okay. And what is needed, are horizonal bars, as in my plot, otherwise the yticks aren't readable.

EDIT (after using the code in ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment):

Here is the plot I am actually seeing, after @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  commented. It is pretty close to what I need.

[image: plot after @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment (setting index)]

Comment: You should always post df's as plain text as it is much more difficult for people to type it out to help you. We are lazy and like copy paste!

Comment: Those are too many questions at once. Or "too broad" in SO speak. Your first question can be done as  `df.set_index("ministere").plot.bar()`. Second question is asked so often, it's actually hard to miss one of the duplicates when searching. Third question may be interesting. But you forgot to tell *how*  you imagine that to look like.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it helped a lot! Now, yeah, how I imagine it.. I would say, the best for me would be to have: 1)  the value of the 'budget2019' on the left side, by the yticks, at the beginning of each ytick's text (between parentheses), and the evolution_percent value in front of each 2 bars of each 'ministere'. I hope you understood what I mean? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use seaborn, you have to use an intermediate dataframe created using `melt` to produce a "long-form" dataframe.

```
df2 = pd.melt(budget, id_vars=['ministere'], value_vars=['budget2018','budget2019'], var_name='year')
```

then plotting of both column is done using the `hue=` parameter:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="value", y="ministere", hue="year", data=df2, palette='pastel')
```

adjusting the labels as requested is fairly easy (and you'll find plenty of other exaples on SO):

```
for i,m in budget.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(s='{:.2f}%'.format(m.loc['evolution_percent']),
                xy=(m.loc[['budget2018','budget2019']].max(),i),
                xytext=(10,0),
                textcoords='offset pixels',
                ha='left',
                va='center'
               )

labels = ['{:s}\n(2019: {:.2f}€)'.format(d.ministere,d.budget2019) for _,d in budget.iterrows()]
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: I tend to understand differences in the dfs in order to plot with ```plotly``` or ```seaborn```. So, what if we needed this plot to be stacked instead of clustered using ```sns```? I see that an argument like ```stacked=True``` does not work.